# How many times is the function called?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

```
Algorithm(a-array, n-length):
      for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
         if(a[1]<a[i]) Swap(a,1,i);  
      for(i=n-1;i>=2;i--)
         if(a[n]<a[i]) Swap(a,n,i);
```

I'm interested in determining how many times `Swap` is called in the code above in the worst case, so I have some questions.

What's the worst case there?

- If I had only the first for loop, it could be said that the worst case for this algorithm is that the array **a** is already sorted in ascending order, and Swap would be called n-1 times.
- If I had only the second loop, the worst case would also be that **a** is already sorted, but this time, the order would be descending. That means that if we consider the first worst case, the `Swap` wouldn't be called in the second loop, and vice versa, i.e. it can't be called in both loops in each iteration.

What should I do now? How to combine those two worst cases that are opposite to each other?
Worst case means that I want to have as many Swap calls as possible. : )

P.S. I see that the complexity is O(n), but I need to estimate as precisely as possible how many times is the Swap executed.

EDIT 1: `Swap(a,i,j)` swaps the elements `a[i]` and `a[j]`.

Comment: Is the second for loop inner loop?

Comment: No, it isn't. The loops are not nested.

Comment: I've tested this algorithm on all possible permutations of an array containing 10 unique elements, and the most swaps performed on any of them is 9. From empirical observation it looks like n-1 swaps is the worst case for an array of size n. But I have no formal proof, which is why this is a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let s and r be the positions of the largest and next to largest elements in the original array. At the end of the first loop:-
 the largest will come to the first position. 
 If r < s then the position of the next to largest will now be r. if r > s it will still be r.
At the end of second loop the next to largest element will be at the end
For the first loop the worst case for fixed s is when all elements upto s are in ascending order. The number of swaps is s.
For the second loop the worst case occurs if the next to largest is closer to the beginning of the array. this occurs when  r < s and all elements after the largest were in descending order in the original array(they will be untouched even after the first loop). The number of swaps is n-s-1
Total = n-1 in the worst case independent of r and s.

eg A = [1 2 5 7 3 4] Here upto max elemnt 7 it is ascending and after that descending
number of swaps = 5

Comment: Thank you, Bug Catcher, you helped me a lot. : )

Answer (score 0):

The worst case for the first loop is that every *a*<sub>*i*</sub> is smaller than *a*<sub>*j*</sub> with 1 ≤ *i* < *j* ≤ *n*. In that case, every *a*<sub>*j*</sub> is swapped with *a*<sub>1</sub> so that at the end *a*<sub>1</sub> is the largest number. This swapping can only happen at most *n*-1 times, e.g.:

```
[1,2,3,4,5] ⟶ [5,1,2,3,4]
```

Similarly, the worst case for the second loop is that every *a*<sub>*i*</sub> is greater than *a*<sub>*j*</sub> with 2 ≤ *i* < *j* ≤ *n*. In that case, every *a*<sub>*i*</sub> is swapped with *a*<sub>*n*</sub> so that at the end *a*<sub>*n*</sub> is the largest number of the sub-array *a*<sub>2</sub>,…,*a*<sub>*n*</sub>. This swapping can only happen at most *n*-2 times, e.g.:

```
[x,4,3,2,1] ⟶ [x,3,2,1,4]
```

Now the tricky part is to combine both conditions as the conditions for a `Swap` call in both loops are mutually exclusive: For any pair *a*<sub>*i*</sub>, *a*<sub>*j*</sub> with 1 ≤ *i* < *j* ≤ *n* and *a*<sub>*i*</sub> < *a*<sub>*j*</sub>, the first loop will call `Swap`. But for any of such pairs, the second loop won’t call `Swap` as it expects the opposite: *a*<sub>*i*</sub> > *a*<sub>*j*</sub>.

So the maximum number of `Swap` calls is *n*-1.

Comment: From my understanding of the question Swap(A, i, j) is a routine that swaps the elements at the i and j positions

Comment: Yes, but I'm sorry for forgetting to mention it in the code: the Swap(a,i,j) swaps the elements a[i] and a[j], so if in the first iteration of the first loop it is found that 1<3, then Swap swaps 1 and 3, so we have A = [3,1,3,3,2]. After that, when a[i]=3,3,2, the Swap is not called, because 3<3 and 3<2 are both false. 
The second loop: with A now being [3,1,3,3,2], Swap is called when we examine 2 and 3 (the 4th and the 5th element in the array), so we have [3,1,3,2,3] in the second iteration. After that, because 3<2,3<3 and 3<1 are false, the Swap is never called again in the loop.